# http post request header both set and not set?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, post

I'm making an iOS app and part of it sends http post requests to php on a server.

I've just made some changes to my code (both in the app and the php), and I've broken something but I'm not sure what. I'm not a PHP expert, although I know the app (obj-c) side well.

In my php I have:

```
$result = array(); //create empty array to fill with results to send back to app

if (isset($_POST["level"])) //this is what is meant to happen
{
        $result["level is set"] = "true";
        //do some stuff
}
else   //this is not meant to happen
{
        $result["level is set"] = "false";

        foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value)  //check to see what actually is set
       {
        $result[$name] =  $value;
       }
}
```

And then the result array I get in my app is:

```
[responseData: {
    Accept = "*/*";
    "Accept-Encoding" = "gzip, deflate";
    "Accept-Language" = "en-us";
    Authorization = "Basic emlwemlwYXBwdXNlcjpEJkIye28sU34tO28=";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 16;
    "Content-Type" = "multipart/form-data, boundary=--boundary";
    Host = my server;
    "User-Agent" = "MyAppName/7 CFNetwork/808.0.2 Darwin/16.4.0";
    "level is set" = false;
    level = 1;
}]
```

Note that "level" is set when I iterate through my headers, but it has followed the "else" path that should only be followed if "level" is not set.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm guessing it is something that is staring me in the face.

thanks

Comment: getallheaders returns all request headers, whereas $_POST is only related to POST. I am not an expert either, but I think the behaviour you are seeing could happen when you pass "level" as a GET parameter. It would not be in POST, but returned by getallheaders.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker that's a good thought, but I haven't changed the part of my code that defines it as a POST request. I double checked it just to make sure. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)`to see what's in $_POST . I would expect `level`not to be in there.

Comment: Also, please note that while it might still be a POST request, the parameter might be passed as a GET parameter.

Comment: @PhilippFlenker Actually I just iterated through them using "foreach($_POST as $key => $value)" instead, and it doesn't find anything. So perhaps you are on to something..

Comment: If you could edit your question to include the code from iOS which does the request, then we could take a look at that one as well.

Comment: I just tried iterating through the GETs using " foreach($_GET as $key => $value)" and it doesn't seem to find anything either. :S

Comment: Headers aren't only GET and POST. Please post your client side code so I can find out where iOS puts `level`...

Comment: Thanks, but that's more easily said than done. I'm using my own generic class for making the request that I use in all my apps, and has always worked, including in this app until a few hours ago. Its about 300 lines long to deal with all the possibilities I need. It gets populated from other classes. I'm going to look through it all to see what I've changed since it worked.

Comment: Ah, I found why it was working before, I had been using "$_SERVER['HTTP_LEVEL']" as a back up, and in the new version I had gotten rid of my back up way, thinking that "$_POST["level"]" was the thing that was working.

Comment: Glad you solved it!